# Given a finite topological space $(\Omega, \tau)$ and $x \in \Omega$, show the smallest open set containing $x$ is homotopic to a point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, homotopy-theory, connectedness

I mainly wanted to check if my solution was correct. (a)-(c) I pretty much have, it is mainly (d) that I am worried about:

**Question:** Let $(\Omega, \tau)$ be a finite topological space.

a) Show for any $x \in \Omega$ there exists a smallest open set containing $x$, denoted $U_x$.

b) Prove $U_x$ is both connected and compact.

c) Prove $U_x$ is also path connected.

d) Prove that $U_x$ is homotopically equivalent to a point.

e) Determine $\pi_1(U_x,x)$

**Attempted Solution:**

(a) Because $\Omega$ is finite, let $\tau=\{U_1,...,U_n\}$ be an ordering of the topology such that $|U_i| \leq |U_{i+1}|$. Let $i\leq n$ be the first positive integer such that $x \in U_i$ and let $U_x=U_i$.

(b) All finite topological spaces are compact, hence $U_x$ is compact.  To see connectedness, suppose not, then we have non-empty open sets $U,V$ such that $U \cup V = U_x$ but $U \cap V=\emptyset$.  WLOG say $x \in U$, then $U_x$ was not the smallest open set containing $x$, a contradiction.

(c) A finite topological space is connected iff it is path connected.

(d) If $U_x$ is already a singleton, we are done.  Otherwise define the homotopy as follows: $F(U_x, 0) = x$ but $F(U_x,t)=\textit{id}_{U_x}$

(e) By (d) we clearly have $\pi_1(U_x,x)=1$ the trivial group.

Comment: For a) I'd use $U_x = \bigcap \{O \in \tau\mid x \in O\}$ which is clearly minimal. b) is fine but c) needs a proof, not just a claim. For d), why is $F$ continuous?

Comment: Nice for (a), but for (c) there is a proof of that in the book I'm using and it is a standard result so I didn't type it up. Does (d) look okay?

Comment: You still haven't justified why $F$ is continuous. Use the fact that $U_x$ is the only open subset of $U_x$ (with the subspace topology) containing $x$.